# Installing Meteor on Windows 7 with cURL

Tags: javascript, curl, installation, meteor

I'm a newbie when it comes to installing/setting up software especially if it involves using the command line.

I'm trying to install Meteor.js on Windows 7 x64 using the following instructions: http://pastebin.com/qQYf23f4

In the command prompt, after going to the directory Meteor is installed, I try running `curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh` but I get the error `The system cannot find the path specified.`

In my Meteor directory, there is a `bin` folder but no `sh` folder inside it...  Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Meteor doesn't yet support Windows officially. Unofficially, have a look at http://win.meteor.com

Comment: There are essentially three options: 1) use a linux VM inside Windows, 2) use a Windows MSI installer, and 3) use the LaunchMeteor exe based downloader. 1 & 2 are available via http://win.meteor.com, 2 & 3 are available from https://github.com/sdarnell/meteor/wiki/Windows

Answer (score 1):

As of release 1.1 that came out recently, Meteor started supporting Windows officially. The official Windows installer is available [here](https://www.meteor.com/install)

Answer (score 0):

Just tried InstallMeteor.exe. Got messeage failed to contact install server and got error following is in the log file:

[2D9F0:8D5C][2016-07-28T11:00:36]i301: Applying execute package: SetupMeteor_UserInstall, action: Install, path: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Package Cache{2DA24988-287C-4531-9B32-88729CBDF7F1}v1.0\SetupMeteor.msi, arguments: ' ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" MSIFASTINSTALL="7" METEOR_DIR="C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\" INSTALL_REG_PATH="SOFTWARE\Meteor Development Group \Meteor\Install" MSICUSTOMERRFILE="C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\Meteor_20160728110033.log.err" PERUSER_INSTALL="1"'
[2D9F0:8D5C][2016-07-28T11:01:01]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.
[2D9F0:8D5C][2016-07-28T11:01:01]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-user MSI package.
[2D9F0:8D5C][2016-07-28T11:01:01]i319: Applied execute package: SetupMeteor_UserInstall, result: 0x80070643, restart: None